# Plotting spectral signature of training data from a supervised classification in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart, training

I need to plot the spectral signature of training data in each of the 8 classes of the supervised classification script I wrote in GEE.
The variable 'training_points' is made of sample points I selected in GEE interface and I merged them using:

```
var Training_Points = Water.merge(Residential).merge(Agricultural).merge(Arbusti).merge(BoschiMisti).merge(Latifoglie).merge(Conifere).merge(BareSoil);
```

The variable 'input 'is an imagecollection as:

```
var input = ee.Image(mean_Summer_IC);
```

Then I used these two variables in the script below:

```
//Create training data
var train = input.sampleRegions({
  collection: Training_Points, 
  properties: ['land_class'], 
  scale: 10,
  tileScale: 2
});

var BANDS = input.bandNames()
var numBands = BANDS.length()
var bandsWithClass = BANDS.add('land_class')
var classIndex = bandsWithClass.indexOf('land_class')

// Use .combine() to get a reducer capable of 
// computing multiple stats on the input
var combinedReducer = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  sharedInputs: true})

// Use .repeat() to get a reducer for each band
// We then use .group() to get stats by class
var repeatedReducer = combinedReducer.repeat(numBands).group(classIndex)

var Training_PointsStats = train.reduceColumns({
    selectors: BANDS.add('land_class'),
    reducer: repeatedReducer,
})

// Result is a dictionary, we do some post-processing to
// extract the results
var groups = ee.List(Training_PointsStats.get('groups'))

var classNames = ee.List(['Water','Residential', 'Agricultural', 'Arbusti', 'BoschiMisti', 'Latifoglie', 'Conifere', 'BareSoil'])

var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(groups.map(function(item) {
  // Extract the means
  var values = ee.Dictionary(item).get('mean')
  var groupNumber = ee.Dictionary(item).get('group')
  var properties = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(BANDS, values)
  var withClass = properties.set('class', classNames.get(groupNumber))
  return ee.Feature(null, withClass)
}))

// Chart spectral signatures of training data
var options = {
  title: 'Average Spectral Signatures',
  hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Reflectance', 
    viewWindowMode:'explicit',
    viewWindow: {
        max:0.6,
        min:0
    }},
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 4,
  series: {
    0: {color: '105af0'},                                   
    1: {color: 'dc350a'}, 
    2: {color: 'caa712'}, 
    3: {color: 'b9ffa4'},
    4: {color: '369b47'},
    5: {color: '21ff2d'},
    6: {color: '275b25'},
    7: {color: 'f7e084'},                         
}};

// Default band names don't sort propertly
// Instead, we can give a dictionary with
// labels for each band in the X-Axis
var bandDescriptions = {
  'B2': 'B2/Blue',
  'B3': 'B3/Green',
  'B4': 'B4/Red',
  'B5': 'B5/Red Edge 1',
  'B6': 'B5/Red Edge 2  ',
  'B7': 'B7/Red Edge 3  ',
  'B8': 'B8/NIR',
  'B8A': 'B8A/Red Edge 4    ',
  'B11': 'B11/SWIR-1',
  'B12': 'B12/SWIR-2'
}

// Create the chart and set options.
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byProperty({
  features: fc,
  xProperties: bandDescriptions,
  seriesProperty: 'class'
})
.setChartType('ScatterChart')
.setOptions(options);

print(chart)

var classChart = function(land_class, label, color) {
  var options = {
  title: 'Spectral Signatures for ' + label + ' Class',
  hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Reflectance', 
    viewWindowMode:'explicit',
    viewWindow: {
        max:0.6,
        min:0
    }},
  lineWidth: 1,
  pointSize: 4,
  };

  var fc = train.filter(ee.Filter.eq('land_class', land_class))
  var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byProperty({
  features: fc,
  xProperties: bandDescriptions,
  })
.setChartType('ScatterChart')
.setOptions(options);

print(chart)
}
classChart(0, 'Water')
classChart(1, 'Residential')
classChart(2, 'Agricultural')
classChart(3, 'Arbusti')
classChart(4, 'BoschiMisti')
classChart(5, 'Latifoglie')
classChart(6, 'Conifere')
classChart(7, 'BareSoil')
```

and I keep receiving errors:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'properties')
> List.get:List index must be between 0 and 7, or -8 and -1.  Found 8.

the series is indeed set from 0 to 7 so I cannot understand why I keep getting this error.
The link to the whole script is here starting from Line 647:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d613222ee468a9afa8abf917b95844ac?accept_repo=users%2Fessepratico%2FPratico_et_al_RemoteSensing_2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by adding these lines to the script:

```
Training_Points = Training_Points.remap({
  lookupIn: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  lookupOut:[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  columnName: 'land_class'
})
```